# Website for Mathematics enigmas?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, big-list, online-resources

I seek some website just for the pleasure of solving mathematics enigmas.
I know this website : [Brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/) I just want to know if you know some others good sites !

Thank you

Comment: +1, I've been trying to find this website but it didn't pop up in the search engines. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: Art of Problem Solving ([aops.com](http://www.aops.com)) has some, I _think_… along with past contest problems and solutions for various contests.

Comment: [This one is the best](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_mathematics#Lists_of_unsolved_problems_in_mathematics)... ;-$)$

Comment: I solved the Riemann Hypothesis a day ago, but hanc marginis exiguitas non caperet.

Answer (score 0):

Making some advertisement for my own website:

[Mathcounterexamples](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/)

It is not about mathematics enigmas, but about mathematics counterexamples. Which are often puzzling. You can look at post titles and try to find examples having the required properties.

For example find an unbounded continuous function over $[0,+\infty)$ having a finite integral. One example: [here](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/unbounded-continuous-function-with-finite-integral/).

Comment: I know it, and for most of them problems here are a bit complex for me but very good to read the solutions ! :)